# jquery div container that updates from mysql every 5 min

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Can anyone please tell me how to write a small div container in HTML that refreshes its  contents from the data in mysql every 5 min.

This is similar to twitter updates in some webpages which show updates as and when tweeted.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#live").load("ajax.php");
    var refreshId = setInterval(function () {
        $("#live").load('ajax.php?randval=' + Math.random());
    }, 3000);
});
```

it calls ajax.php in first load and every 3 seconds to #live div.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `setInterval` function to make AJAX calls:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $('#dynamicDiv').load('DynamicDivData.php');
}, 5 * 60 * 1000);    //300,000 milliseconds.
```

Where `DynamicDivData.php` connects to the database and returns the HTML to put in the `<div>`.

To avoid caching issues, you can append a random number in the querystring:

```
$('#dynamicDiv').load('DynamicDivData.php?NoCache=' + Math.random());
```